# DRF: Pagination without queryset

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to make use of Django Rest Framework's pagination mechanisms in my case without success.

```
class TransactionView(viewsets.ViewSet):

    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        # fetching data from external API...

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=list_of_json, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors) 


class TransactionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # Serializer (transaction's) fields ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return APITransaction(**validated_data) 


class APITransaction(object):

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ...):
        self.arg1 = arg1 
        ...
```

The problem is that registering the `pagination_class` (like I have done for the rest of my resources which are represented by Models), doesn't work since the data are created/fetched on the fly, thus I don't have a Model/queryset.

Any ideas on how I could use DRF's pagination mechanism?

Comment: Hello, how did you solve this? Did you follow @Linovia 's reponse and implemented your own pagination class?

Comment: I didn't have time to follow the best practice road here, so I made a function that builds the response manually using `django.core.paginator` to paginate the `list_of_jsons` and building a `dict` with `count, next, previous, numPages, results` which I return as `return JsonResponse(the_dict, status=200, safe=False)`. I will search around for the actual code and submit a new answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the class I wound up creating and using locally for this sort of thing. (Thanks to stelios above for the initial clues.) Of course the contents of "data" must be JSONable.

```
from typing import List, Any
from collections import OrderedDict
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.request import Request

class ListPaginator:
    def __init__(self, request: Request):
        # Hidden HtmlRequest properties/methods found in Request.
        self._url_scheme = request.scheme
        self._host = request.get_host()
        self._path_info = request.path_info

    def paginate_list(self, data: List[Any], page_size: int, page_number: int) -> JsonResponse:
        paginator = Paginator(data, page_size)
        page = paginator.page(page_number)

        previous_url = None
        next_url = None
        if self._host and self._path_info:
            if page.has_previous():
                previous_url = '{}://{}{}?limit={}&page={}'.format(self._url_scheme, self._host, self._path_info, page_size, page.previous_page_number())
            if page.has_next():
                next_url = '{}://{}{}?limit={}&page={}'.format(self._url_scheme, self._host, self._path_info, page_size, page.next_page_number())

        response_dict = OrderedDict([
            ('count', len(data)),
            ('next', next_url),
            ('previous', previous_url),
            ('results', page.object_list)
        ])
        return JsonResponse(response_dict, status=200, safe=False)
```

Comment: I think it is important to notice that it would be inefficient to fetch and save all data in a list and then filter it according to the page number.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reuse existing DRF's pagination because they are supposed to work with queryset.
However, you may roll your own class by inheriting [`BasePagination`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L145) though I haven't done myself.

Comment: Don't think that's helpful - BasePagination is also fundamentally about the "paginate_queryset" approach. I'd also like to paginate a list; I'm going to try stelios's approach above.

Comment: you're right this is not helpfull. I should have closed this question as too broad in the first place.